# Replace into and increment

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, on a simple table [id, title, counter], I would like a single SQL query to create a row if title doesn't exist or increment counter if it exist.

Is this possible?

I tried to use the

```sql
MariaDB [local1bdd]> show columns from wp_jott; REPLACE INTO wp_jott (title, lang, count_ok, count_ko) values ('okok', 'en', $count_ok+1, 1) where title='okok'; select * from wp_jott;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lang     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| count_ok | int(11)          | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| count_ko | int(11)          | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0,001 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where title='okok'' at line 1
+----+-------+------+----------+----------+
| id | title | lang | count_ok | count_ko |
+----+-------+------+----------+----------+
|  1 | okok  | en   |        1 |        1 |
|  2 | okok  | en   |        1 |        1 |
+----+-------+------+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,000 sec)

MariaDB [local1bdd]>
```

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: That was not what I was asking for... my "primary key" is the title, but it is not commun to use string as a primary key. Can you read again before saying it is duplicate ?

Comment: It's the only way AFAIK.

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` doens't have a `WHERE` clause. It doesn't need it, it automatically looks for the matching rows in the `VALUES`.